# Counting Solutions of Summation with n Whole Number Variables

Tags: combinatorics

Given $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$,... $x_n$ are n whole numbers such that
$ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + .....+ x_n $ = K

I seek to determine the count of solutions under the following conditions:

i) All variables $x_i$are different.

ii)  Exactly two variables $x_i$ are equal while the rest are distinct

My attempt was to find the solutions by stars and bars technique, but honestly, I don't know how to categorize the solutions.

I am a high school student and don't know much (Polya's Theorem and partitions)  so I thought to solve it the cumbersome way but I would totally get it if it requires higher understanding of the subject. I hope its allowed to ask the solution for two conditions. If not, please prioritze the first one.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Is that okay? @N.F.Taussig